# Query to select rows that contain uppercase words

Tags: mysql, regex

The following query produces some rows that do NOT contain UPPERCASE words and I'm not sure why.

Any ideas?

```
SELECT exampleColumn FROM table WHERE exampleColumn REGEXP '[[:upper:]+]$';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this,

```
SELECT exampleColumn FROM table WHERE exampleColumn REGEXP '^[[:upper:]]+$';
```

This selects only the columns having uppercase letters only.

Update:

```
SELECT exampleColumn FROM table WHERE exampleColumn REGEXP '\b[[:upper:]]+\b';
```

Comment: or try `^[A-Z]+$`

Comment: I'm trying to find rows where the exampleColumn contains something like this:  'This home remedy was AMAZING in how effective it was'.  In other words, only return rows where there is some word that is ALL CAPS.

Comment: @NestMan check my update.. or `'\\b[[:upper:]]+\\b'`

Comment: I tried your updated query and that didn't work.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  You will probably see that `exampleColumn` is collated in some `_ci` collation.

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| 'abc' REGEXP '^[[:upper:]]+$' COLLATE utf8_bin |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                              0 |  -- correctly does what you want
+------------------------------------------------+

+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 'abc' REGEXP '^[[:upper:]]+$' COLLATE utf8_general_ci |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                     1 |  -- ignores case
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Addenda**

The default `COLLATION` for `CHARSET=latin1` is `latin1_general_ci`.  That is, it will ignore case, similar to the example I provided.

Here are two 'solutions':

Plan A:  Change the collation of your latin1 column to `COLLATION latin1_bin`.

Plan B:  Use this in the query:  `REGEXP '^[[:upper:]]+$' COLLATE latin1_bin`.

Comment: Rick, here is what the SHOW CREATE TABLE revealed:  ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1